# Different versions of python3-catkin-pkg-modules are distributed on packages.ros.org

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems different versions of `python3-catkin-pkg-modules` are distributed on packages.ros.org.
Therefore, when I tried to install `python3-catkin-pkg-modules`, sometimes it fails, and sometimes succeeds.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS Melodic

### How to reproduce the problem

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh

# apt update && apt install -y lsb-release gnupg
# sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
# apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
# apt update
# apt install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docutils-common libfreetype6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpng16-16 libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 multiarch-support python3-dateutil
  python3-docutils python3-olefile python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-pygments python3-pyparsing
  python3-roman python3-six sgml-base tzdata ucf xml-core
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils docutils-doc fonts-linuxlibertine | ttf-linux-libertine texlive-lang-french
  texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended python-pil-doc python3-pil-dbg python3-setuptools
  ttf-bitstream-vera python-pyparsing-doc sgml-base-doc debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docutils-common libfreetype6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpng16-16 libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 multiarch-support python3-catkin-pkg-modules
  python3-dateutil python3-docutils python3-olefile python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-pygments
  python3-pyparsing python3-roman python3-six sgml-base tzdata ucf xml-core
0 upgraded, 28 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.0 kB/3179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-catkin-pkg-modules all 0.4.20-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

# apt install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules # try again
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docutils-common libfreetype6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpng16-16 libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 multiarch-support python3-dateutil
  python3-docutils python3-olefile python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-pygments
  python3-pyparsing python3-roman python3-six sgml-base tzdata ucf xml-core
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils docutils-doc fonts-linuxlibertine | ttf-linux-libertine texlive-lang-french
  texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended python-pil-doc python3-pil-dbg python3-setuptools
  ttf-bitstream-vera python-pyparsing-doc sgml-base-doc debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docutils-common libfreetype6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libpng16-16 libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 multiarch-support python3-catkin-pkg-modules
  python3-dateutil python3-docutils python3-olefile python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-pygments
  python3-pyparsing python3-roman python3-six sgml-base tzdata ucf xml-core
0 upgraded, 28 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.8 kB/3179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-catkin-pkg-modules all 0.4.18-1 [41.8 kB]
Fetched 41.8 kB in 6s (7383 B/s)
```

### Investigation

I can see that there are three addresses for packages.ros.org.

```
$ host packages.ros.org
packages.ros.org is an alias for ftp.osuosl.org.
ftp.osuosl.org has address 64.50.233.100
ftp.osuosl.org has address 140.211.166.134
ftp.osuosl.org has address 64.50.236.52
ftp.osuosl.org has IPv6 address 2605:bc80:3010::134
ftp.osuosl.org has IPv6 address 2600:3402:200:227::2
ftp.osuosl.org has IPv6 address 2600:3404:200:237::2
```

These two have `python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb`.

- http://140.211.166.134/pub/ros-ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/
- http://64.50.233.100/pub/ros-ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/

However, `64.50.236.52` has `python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.18-1_all.deb`, and when DNS selected this address, it fails.

- http://64.50.236.52/pub/ros-ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/

You can confirm the problem by directly downloading `python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb`.

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 /bin/sh

# apt update && apt install -y wget
# wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb
--2020-05-18 11:38:32--  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 64.50.236.52, 140.211.166.134, 64.50.233.100, ...
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|64.50.236.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-05-18 11:38:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.

# wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb
--2020-05-18 11:38:40--  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-catkin-pkg-modules/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 140.211.166.134, 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52, ...
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|140.211.166.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 41968 (41K) [application/x-troff-man]
Saving to: 'python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb'

python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb          100%[=====================================================================================================================>]  40.98K  29.4KB/s    in 1.4s    

2020-05-18 11:38:47 (29.4 KB/s) - 'python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.20-1_all.deb' saved [41968/41968]
```

Is this the correct state, or did I made any mistakes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352605/different-versions-of-python3-catkin-pkg-modules-are-distributed-on-packages.ros.org/) by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-18**:
I've seen this as well, but for `python3-vcstool` ([ros-industrial/industrial_ci#509](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/pull/509) and [ros-industrial-consortium/tesseract#292](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/tesseract/pull/292)).

> I can see that there are three addresses for packages.ros.org.

this could be an issue with round-robin DNS and not all hosts being in-sync.

> Is this the correct state, or did I made any mistakes?

No, I believe your analysis is correct.

We'll have to wait for either:

1. the hosts to get back in sync by themselves, or
2. the admin(s) of the hosts to force them to sync

@tfoote @nuclearsandwich?

---

Edit: now also on ROS Discourse: comment on [Preparing for Kinetic Sync 2020-05-13](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-kinetic-sync-2020-05-13/14091).

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2020-05-18**:
Thank you for your quick reply. I'll watch the discourse thread.

Could you tell me whether this is an accidental problem or could happen regularly?

> this could be an issue with round-robin DNS and not all hosts being in-sync.

Do you mean that this kind of problem can frequently happen right after releasing a new version?
If so, do you know about how long we should wait for syncing?
Also, what is the best way to let admins know the problem when I find it? (As you did, replying to the Preparing thread?)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-18**:\

> Could you tell me whether this is an accidental problem or could happen regularly?

This is the first time this has happened, IIRC.

> Do you mean that this kind of problem can frequently happen right after releasing a new version?

No, that's not what I meant. What I wrote is that it seems there is a round-robin DNS configuration and *in this particular case* one of the hosts involved in that seems to have gone out-of-sync with the others.

> If so, do you know about how long we should wait for syncing?

I would not know.

> Also, what is the best way to let admins know the problem when I find it?

Posting either here or on ROS Discourse, maybe in the [Packaging and Release Management](https://discourse.ros.org/c/release/16) category. Or perhaps the [Buildfarm](https://discourse.ros.org/c/buildfarm/20) category.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-18**:
Seems it's being worked on: [Incident Report for ROS: packages.ros.org mirrors out of sync](https://status.ros.org/incidents/9ptv1lj2p0lg).

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2020-05-18**:
I understand, thank you! I'll wait for a while and check again after it's fixed.

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2020-05-18**:
Oh, now `64.50.236.52` seems to be synced. Will check other packages as well for just in case.

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2020-05-18**:
I've tried the installation of ROS melodic + colcon several times using docker, and it seems working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [Incident Report for ROS: packages.ros.org mirrors out of sync](https://status.ros.org/incidents/9ptv1lj2p0lg), this should now be fixed:

> **Resolved**
>
> The mirrors are re-synchronized.

Original incident report:

> We have identified that one of our 3 mirrors of packages.ros.org is out of sync. We're working with our hosting provider to bring the new one up to date.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0